# Get compile error with VBA while tracking changes

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors

I get a compile error "byRef argument type mismatch." ANy insite on what is prompting this or how i can clear it? i checked the other sub fuctions and vOldArr is a range in all of them. the error comes in the Worksheet_Change sub

```
    Dim vOldVal
    Dim vOldArr
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)
    vOldVal = target.Value
    Set vOldArr = target
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

     Call Get_Dirction(vOldVal, target, vOldArr)

End Sub

Sub Get_Dirction(vOldVal As Variant, target As Variant, vOldArr As Range)
    If target.Count = 1 Then
        Call Check_Change_Single(vOldVal, target)
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Call Check_Change_Mult(vOldArr, target)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: how is your Get_dirction written? What is its signature? (The first line that says Sub Get_dirction(........)) And if vOldArr is a range, why not declare it as such in the top part (rather than as variant)

Comment: `Sub Get_Dirction(vOldVal As Variant, target As Variant, vOldArr As Range)
    If target.Count = 1 Then
        Call Check_Change_Single(vOldVal, target)
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Call Check_Change_Mult(vOldArr, target)
    End If
End Sub`

Comment: vOldArr is declared as a variant implicitly at the top, change to explicit As Range, also use Option Explicit at top of code.

Comment: Code or details do not belong in comments. Instead, [edit] your post and add them there. Once you've done so, you can pass the time while waiting for an answer by doing what was asked when creating your account - take the [tour] and read the [help] guidelines, particularly [ask] and [mcve] - so you'll be better prepared when posting your next question here.

Comment: great, that got me though that error and into another, i will continue to  work, thanks for your help

Comment: @QHarr: I have deleted my answer. Yoy may want to post your comment.  :)

Comment: No put yours back. I get to learn from yours normally!

Comment: Both answer! can i ask another one?

Comment: @QHarr: Done. Actually, I did not see your solution in comment else I wouldn't posted an answer. If you do change your mind let me know and I will delete my answer and you can put yours :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Your answer is a lot more useful and informative to anyone looking for a solution so i don't mind at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An argument passed `ByRef` must have the precise data type expected in the procedure.

For example, this error occurs if you try to pass a `Long` variable when an `Integer` is expected.

**Example**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim SampleValue As Long

    SampleValue = 1

    SomeProcedure SampleValue
End Sub


Sub SomeProcedure(l As Integer)
    '
    '~~> Some Code
    '
End Sub
```

When you run the code you will see the error that you are getting

[image]

In your case you have

```
Sub Get_Dirction(vOldVal As Variant, target As Variant, vOldArr As Range)
```

`Get_Dirction` is expecting *2 variants and 1 range*.

`vOldArr` is expected as a `Range` but is gettng a `Variant` and hence the error.

[image]

**Solution**

Declare `vOldArr` As `Range` in `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)`

OR

Declare `vOldArr` As `Variant` in `Sub Get_Dirction(vOldVal As Variant, target As Variant, vOldArr As Range)`